# Compare month in timestamp

Tags: oracle, timestamp

I have a table with TIMESTAMP datatype and I need to compare month value to select all table values. Example the created is the field and wanted to get all the rows which is created between November & December of any year. Tried with below query and it don't work.

select * from table_name where TO_CHAR(created_time, 'mon') in ('nov','dec')

Comment: The `mon` format model depends on the national settings, does this work? `to_char(created_time, 'mon', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = american')`

Comment: I'm able to retrieve the month in the select clause but not able to use the result to compare in where clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `EXTRACT`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  EXTRACT( MONTH from created_time ) IN ( 11, 12 )
```

Or, you can use `TO_CHAR( created_time, 'MM' )` to get the numeric month value (and not worry about language settings as you would have to with the `MON` format model):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  TO_CHAR( created_time, 'MM' ) IN ( '11', '12' )
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=66b5c7280c5fa3931ce92fcdc3cd4eaa)

Comment: On the TO_CHAR, value 11, 12 in where clause is without quote I believe.

Comment: @Shankar `TO_CHAR` returns a string value so the `IN` clause can also be string. If you leave the quotes out then Oracle has to perform an implicit cast from the number to a string and you are creating (a little) more work when evaluating the query.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are several ways to achieve this.

1.Using the `nlsparam` of `to_char` function

> The 'nlsparam' argument specifies the language in which month and day names and abbreviations are returned.

Example

```
SQL> create table t ( c1 timestamp ) ;

Table created.

SQL> alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss.rr' ;

Session altered.

SQL> insert into t values ( systimestamp - 30 ) ;

1 row created.

SQL>  insert into t values ( systimestamp ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> select * from t ;

C1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
30.07.2020 09:29:35.20
29.08.2020 09:29:42.20

SQL> select value from nls_database_parameters where parameter='NLS_LANGUAGE' ;

VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AMERICAN

SQL> select c1 , to_char(c1, 'mon' , 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = american') as mon from t ;

C1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MON
------------
30.07.2020 09:29:35
jul

29.08.2020 09:29:42
aug
```

2.However, to avoid depending in the language, you can use `extract` and compare the number of the month which is the same in any language. In this case you need to convert the timestamp to a date, but before you need to set the `nls_timestamp_format` to the specific format.

```
SQL> alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL>  select c1 , extract(month from to_date(c1,'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')) from t ;

C1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
EXTRACT(MONTHFROMTO_DATE(C1,'DD.MM.YYYYHH24:MI:SS'))
----------------------------------------------------
30.07.2020 09:29:35
                                                   7

29.08.2020 09:29:42
                                                   8
```

Comment: select c1 , to_char(c1, 'mon' , 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = american') as mon from t where  to_char(c1, 'mon' , 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = american') = 'jul' 

Will the where clause work?

Comment: it should work, as long as the data stored in your table matches the nls_language language